# How can I superimpose a graphic over a dark t-shirt?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want put my site logo over a t-shirt. I've successfully done so with a white t-shirt by following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPxxbRVN6Tg) video tutorial.

With a black shirt, I have a problem with the multiply blend mode. Here is a screenshot for a white t-shirt:

[image: logo superimposed on white t-shirt]

And here is one for a black t-shirt

[image: logo superimposed on black t-shirt]

How can I place a logo over a black t-shirt?

Comment: "You" is black. The t-shirt is black. That's not going to work without changing the art.

Comment: "I have a problem with the multiply blend mode" - `Multiply` makes things darker. The opposite of `Multiply` is `Screen`. Depends on the artwork, but might just work. Note that `Screen` with black typically has no effect, like `Multiply` with white, so you may need to change the logo depending on how it looks if there are black/dark areas that need to be prominent - e.g. swap black for white, dark for light, then use Screen. And make sure there's no white background...use black if you need to fade anything into a background colour.

Answer (score 3):

It is **exceptionally** rare that the same artwork is appropriate for both light and dark printing. In 99% of cases you need to *change the artwork* to work on a dark background if it was designed for a light background.

Most companies delivering logos will deliver a "reversed" logo version for just this purpose.

Obviously you are not using the YouTube logo for your shirts. Without seeing the are **you are using** there's no telling what your specific issue may be.

The short, general, answer is.... **reverse the artwork if placing it on a black background.**

Answer (score 0):

i think its because this logo is transparent and low opacity (and in this logo the word "You" is black naturally it isn't look good on a black shirt so you should change color! ) or change background color to white(not transparent) 
here the picture of' my advice:[image]

Comment: but this looks very much not desirable.